# Django - right way to join not-django tables

Tags: django, foreign-keys, django-model-field

I have old cms database, structure isn't perfect and it can't be modified but i need to query using django

TABLE `posts` 
      (`post_id`)

TABLE `posts_text` 
      (`post_id`,
       `post_text`)

TABLE `episode` 
      (`id`,
      `season_id`,
      `episode_name`)

TABLE `episode_post_relationship` 
      (`id`,
      `season_id`,
      `episode_id`,
      `post_id`)

Please help me to create django models with right tables relationships. Should i use OneToOneField, ForeignKey, ManyToManyField and etc or pure join?

I'm trying to get **Episodes** from **episode_post_relationship** table with `posts_text`.`posts_text` and `posts`.`some_other_col`
but can't specify that `episode_post_relationship` table should join `posts_text` on `post_id` and the same for `posts` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [per documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/legacy-databases/), you can connect to legacy Databases as well. For that, you need to connect your current Django project to that DB, for example, create a new project by `django-admin.py startproject yourproject`, then go to settings and update the `DATABASES` setup like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': 'DB_NAME',
        'USER': 'DB_USER',
        'PASSWORD': 'DB_PASSWORD',
        'HOST': 'localhost',   # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

And then run `python manage.py inspectdb`. You can also output it as a model like `python manage.py inspectdb > models.py`

#### Update:

From what I can see, your DB should be:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    post_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'posts'

class PostText(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
    post_text = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'posts_text'

class Season(models.Model):
    # season fields
    class Meta:
       db_table = 'season'

class Episode(models.Model):
    season = models.ForeignKey(Season)
    episode_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)  # depends on your DB
    posts = models.ManyToManyField(Post, through="EpisodePost")

    class Meta:
        db_table='episode'

class EpisodePost(models.Model):
    season = models.ForeignKey(Season)
    episode = models.ForeignKey(Episode)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)

    class Meta:
        db_table='episode_post_relationship'
```

**But, before you do anything with above relations, please make sure to have a backup of your current DB.**

Comment: used inspectdb already, got models, but there're nothing about tables relationships anyway

Comment: @pyAndy please see my update section of the answer. Hope it helps!!